# Processing apache logs quickly

Tags: apache, awk, large-data-volumes

I'm currently running an awk script to process a large (8.1GB) access-log file, and it's taking forever to finish. In 20 minutes, it wrote 14MB of the (1000 +- 500)MB I expect it to write, and I wonder if I can process it much faster somehow.

Here is the awk script:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '{t=$4" "$5; gsub("[\[\]\/]"," ",t); sub(":"," ",t);printf("%s,",$1);system("date -d \""t"\" +%s");}' $1
```

---

*EDIT:*

For non-awkers, the script reads each line, gets the date information, modifies it to a format the utility `date` recognizes and calls it to represent the date as the number of seconds since 1970, finally returning it as a line of a .csv file, along with the IP.

**Example input:** 189.5.56.113 - - [22/Jan/2010:05:54:55 +0100] "GET (...)"

**Returned output:** 189.5.56.113,124237889

Comment: Perhaps you could describe what the script does so us non-awkers can write a faster replacement in another language? From a glance though, spawning a new process via system() on every record gotta be pretty slow.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@OP, your script is slow mainly due to the excessive call of system date command for every line in the file, and its a big file as well (in the GB). If you have gawk, use its internal mktime() command to do the date to epoch seconds conversion

```
awk 'BEGIN{
   m=split("Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec",d,"|")
   for(o=1;o<=m;o++){
      date[d[o]]=sprintf("%02d",o)
    }
}
{
    gsub(/\[/,"",$4); gsub(":","/",$4); gsub(/\]/,"",$5)
    n=split($4, DATE,"/")
    day=DATE[1]
    mth=DATE[2]
    year=DATE[3]
    hr=DATE[4]
    min=DATE[5]
    sec=DATE[6]
    MKTIME= mktime(year" "date[mth]" "day" "hr" "min" "sec)
    print $1,MKTIME

}' file
```

output

```
$ more file
189.5.56.113 - - [22/Jan/2010:05:54:55 +0100] "GET (...)"
$ ./shell.sh    
189.5.56.113 1264110895
```

Comment: Removing the system() call made my program 10x faster!

Answer (score 2):

If you really really need it to be faster, you can do what I did.  I rewrote an Apache log file analyzer using Ragel.  Ragel allows you to mix regular expressions with C code.  The regular expressions get transformed into very efficient C code and then compiled.  Unfortunately, this requires that you are *very comfortable* writing code in C.  I no longer have this analyzer.  It processed 1 GB of Apache access logs in 1 or 2 seconds.

You may have limited success removing unnecessary printfs from your awk statement and replacing them with something simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `gawk`, you can massage your date and time into a format that `mktime` (a `gawk` function) understands. It will give you the same timestamp you're using now and save you the overhead of repeated `system()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

This little Python script handles a ~400MB worth of copies of your example line in about 3 minutes on my machine producing ~200MB of output (keep in mind your sample line was quite short, so that's a handicap):

```
import time

src = open('x.log', 'r')
dest = open('x.csv', 'w')

for line in src:
    ip = line[:line.index(' ')]
    date = line[line.index('[') + 1:line.index(']') - 6]
    t = time.mktime(time.strptime(date, '%d/%b/%Y:%X'))
    dest.write(ip)
    dest.write(',')
    dest.write(str(int(t)))
    dest.write('\n')

src.close()
dest.close()
```

A minor problem is that it doesn't handle timezones (strptime() problem), but you could either hardcode that or add a little extra to take care of it.

But to be honest, something as simple as that should be just as easy to rewrite in C.

Answer (score 1):

```
gawk '{
    dt=substr($4,2,11); 
    gsub(/\//," ",dt); 
    "date -d \""dt"\" +%s"|getline ts; 
    print $1, ts
}' yourfile
```