# Converting dates in AWK

Tags: datetime, command-line, awk

I have a file containing many columns of text, including a timestamp along the lines of `Fri Jan 02 18:23` and I need to convert that date into `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM` format.

I have been trying to use the standard `date' tool with awk getline to do the conversion, but I can't quite figure out how to pass the fields into the 'date' command in the format it expects (quoted with " or 's,) as getline needs the command string enclosed in quotes too.

Something like `"date -d '$1 $2 $3 $4' +'%D %H:%M'" | getline var`

Now that I think about it, I guess what I'm really asking is how to embed awk variables into a string.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you can try this. Assuming just the date you specified is in the file

```
awk '
{
    cmd ="date \"+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M\" -d \""$1" "$2" "$3" "$4"\""
    cmd | getline var
    print var
    close(cmd)
}' file
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
01/02/2010 18:23
```

and if you are not using GNU tools, like if you are in Solaris for example, use nawk

```
nawk 'BEGIN{
   m=split("Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec",d,"|")
   for(o=1;o<=m;o++){
      months[d[o]]=sprintf("%02d",o)
   }
   cmd="date +%Y"
   cmd|getline yr
   close(cmd)
}
{
    day=$3
    mth=months[$2]
    print mth"/"day"/"yr" "$4
} ' file
```

Comment: Relying on a non-standard 'date' flag and then a pipe isn't even as legitimate as calling an inline Perl script to do the work.

Comment: @gary: a bit harsh. If he has gnu tools, why not use their capabilities?

Comment: @glenn: Maybe ghostdog has gnu, but OP was asking about awk.  And rather than executing an external command (date) for each line, he really should have thought more.

Comment: @gary, firstly, i may have interpreted the qns wrongly. since OP uses date -d , I assume he uses GNU date. Then if he has GNU date, i assume he has gawk. Secondly, i am only showing him how to do it the way he had wanted it. I added in the rest myself, but FWIW, he may only want to process 1 or few lines. Of course i don't recommend calling date for every line like what i say here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114958/processing-apache-logs-quickly/2115940#2115940. Lastly, OP should come and clarify what OS he is using before we even make conclusions

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer my question.  Building the 'cmd' string before the getline and pipe is all I actually needed.  I'm on Ubuntu 9.10, and only working a few dozen lines at a time.

Comment: @ghostdog: OK, my error. OP did have GNU.  I guess I thought an experienced user should have at least suggested a solution without an external cmd for each line,  like Dennis's original or your second solution.

Answer (score 26):

If you're using gawk, you don't need the external `date` which can be [expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114958/processing-apache-logs-quickly) to call repeatedly:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
   m=split("Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec",d,"|")
   for(o=1;o<=m;o++){
      months[d[o]]=sprintf("%02d",o)
    }
format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"
}
{
split($4,time,":")
date = (strftime("%Y") " " months[$2] " " $3 " " time[1] " " time[2] " 0")
print strftime(format, mktime(date))
}'
```

Thanks to **ghostdog74** for the months array from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114958/processing-apache-logs-quickly/2115940#2115940).

Comment: +1 for letting awk do all the work. Requires gawk for `strftime()`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue converting a date from RRDTool databases using rrdfetch but prefer one liners that I've been using since Apollo computer days.

Data looked like this:

```
localTemp             rs1Temp             rs2Temp      thermostatMode
1547123400: 5.2788174937e+00 4.7788174937e+00 -8.7777777778e+00 2.0000000000e+00
1547123460: 5.1687014581e+00 4.7777777778e+00 -8.7777777778e+00 2.0000000000e+00
```

One liner:

```
rrdtool fetch -s -14400 thermostatDaily.rrd MAX | sed s/://g | awk '{print "echo ""\`date -r" $1,"\`" " " $2 }' | sh
```

Result:

```
Thu Jan 10 07:25:00 EST 2019 5.3373432378e+00
Thu Jan 10 07:26:00 EST 2019 5.2788174937e+00
```

On the face of it this doesn't look very efficient to me but this kind of methodology has always proven to be fairly low overhead under most circumstances even for very large files on very low power computer (like 25Mhz NeXT Machines).  Yes Mhz.

Sed deletes the colon, awk is used to print the other various commands of interest including just echoing the awk variables and sh or bash executes the resulting string.

For methodology or large files or streams I just head the first few lines and gradually build up the one liner.  Throw away code.