# Awk/Perl convert textfile to csv with sensible format

Tags: linux, perl, awk

I have a historical autogenerated logfile with the following format that I would like to convert to a csv file prior to uploading to a database

```
--------------------------------------
Thu Jul  8 09:34:12 BST 2010
BLUE Head 1
Duration = 20 s
Activity = 14.9 MBq
Sensitivity = 312 cps/MBq
--------------------------------------
Thu Jul  8 09:34:55 BST 2010
BLUE Head 1
Duration = 20 s
Activity = 14.9 MBq
Sensitivity = 318 cps/MBq
--------------------------------------
Thu Jul  8 10:13:39 BST 2010
RED Head 1
Duration = 20 s
Activity = 14.9 MBq
Sensitivity = 307 cps/MBq
--------------------------------------
Thu Jul  8 10:14:10 BST 2010
RED Head 1
Duration = 20 s
Activity = 14.9 MBq
Sensitivity = 305 cps/MBq
--------------------------------------
Mon Jul 19 10:11:18 BST 2010
BLUE Head 1
Duration = 20 s
Activity = 12.4 MBq
Sensitivity = 326 cps/MBq
--------------------------------------
Mon Jul 19 10:12:09 BST 2010
BLUE Head 1
Duration = 20 s
Activity = 12.4 MBq
Sensitivity = 333 cps/MBq
--------------------------------------
Mon Jul 19 10:13:57 BST 2010
RED Head 1
Duration = 20 s
Activity = 12.4 MBq
Sensitivity = 338 cps/MBq
--------------------------------------
Mon Jul 19 10:14:45 BST 2010
RED Head 1
Duration = 20 s
Activity = 12.4 MBq
Sensitivity = 340 cps/MBq
--------------------------------------
```

I would like to convert the logfile to the following format

```
Date,Camera,Head,Duration,Activity
08/07/10,BLUE,1,20,14.9
08/07/10,BLUE,1,20,14.9
08/07/10,RED,1,20,14.9
08/07/10,RED,1,20,14.9
```

I have used awk to get me close to what I wish

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "Date,Camera,Head,Duration,Activity";RS = "--------------------------------------"; FS="\n";}; {OFS=",";split($3, a, " ");split($4,b, " "); split($5,c," ");print $2,a[1],a[3],b[3],c[3]}' sensitivity.txt > sensitivity.csv
```

which gives me

```
Date,Camera,Head,Duration,Activity
,,,,
Thu Jul  8 09:34:12 BST 2010,BLUE,1,20,14.9
Thu Jul  8 09:34:55 BST 2010,BLUE,1,20,14.9
Thu Jul  8 10:13:39 BST 2010,RED,1,20,14.9
Thu Jul  8 10:14:10 BST 2010,RED,1,20,14.9
```

How can I

(a) get rid of the 4 output field separators in line 4
(b) Convert the date format from Thu Jul  8 09:34:12 BST 2010 to DD/MM/YY (Can I do this in pure awk or by piping to perl)

Comment: For the date conversion, look at the first answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121896/converting-dates-in-awk

Comment: And for the useless commas, just check the values of $2, a, b, c, etc... (if ($2) { print ... })

Comment: I don't think I've seen anyone ask to convert 4-digit years to 2-digit years in their dates since 2000 rolled along. Seriously consider using a YYYYMMDD date format so you can distinguish 1999 from 2099 and trivially sort your data by date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This straight forward `awk` script will do the job:

```
BEGIN {
    n=split("Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec",month,"|")
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        month_index[month[i]] = i
    }
    print "Date,Camera,Head,Duration,Activity"  
}
/^-*$/{
    i=0
    next
}
{
    i++
}
i==1{
    printf "%02d/%02d/%02d,",$3,month_index[$2],substr($6,3)
}
i==2{
    printf "%s,%d,",$1,$3
}
i==3{
    printf "%d,",$3
}
i==4{
    printf "%.1f\n",$3
}
```

Outputs:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
08/07/10,BLUE,1,20,14.9
08/07/10,BLUE,1,20,14.9
08/07/10,RED,1,20,14.9
08/07/10,RED,1,20,14.9
19/07/10,BLUE,1,20,12.4
19/07/10,BLUE,1,20,12.4
19/07/10,RED,1,20,12.4
19/07/10,RED,1,20,12.4
```

Comment: Your month array will contain 24 entries instead of 12. It'll work as long as the OP doesn't want to print all of the months. Consider using 2 arrays for monthNr2Nm and monthNm2Nr.

Comment: @EdMorton I know, I was just being lazy, I don't see the OP wanting to iterate over the array but changed it just in case.

Comment: @sudo_O - agreed but other people looking for answers to "similar" questions might see it. Mostly I think it helps with clarity if you have 2 separate arrays, even if the one used in the split is just named "tmp" or something.

Answer (score 2):

@sudo_O's answer is fine but here's an alternative:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ RS="---+\n"; OFS=","; months="JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec" }
NR==1{ print "Date","Camera","Head","Duration","Activity"; next }
{ print sprintf("%04d%02d%02d",$6,(match(months,$2)+2)/3,$3),$7,$9,$12,$16 }

$ gawk -f tst.awk file
Date,Camera,Head,Duration,Activity
20100708,BLUE,1,20,14.9
20100708,BLUE,1,20,14.9
20100708,RED,1,20,14.9
20100708,RED,1,20,14.9
20100719,BLUE,1,20,12.4
20100719,BLUE,1,20,12.4
20100719,RED,1,20,12.4
20100719,RED,1,20,12.4
```

Note that I used GNU awk above so I could set the RS to more than a single character. With other awks just convert all the "---..."s lines to a blank line or control character or something and set RS accordingly before running the script.

If you don't like my suggested date format, tweak the sprintf() to suit.

Answer (score 1):

I figured I would show how to actually parse the input, rather than just performing string transformations.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Date::Parse;
use Date::Format;
use Text::CSV;

sub convert_date{
  my $time = str2time($_[0]);
  # iso 8601 style:
  return time2str('%Y-%m-%d',$time); # YYYY-MM-DD

  # or the outdated style output you wanted
  return time2str('%d/%m/%y',$time); # DD/MM/YY
}

my %multiply_table = (
  s => 1,
  m => 60,
  h => 60 * 60,
  d => 60 * 60 * 24,
);
sub convert_duration{
  my($d,$s) = $_[0] =~ /^ \s* (\d+) \s* (\w) \s* $/x;
  die "Invalid duration '$_[0]'" unless $d && $s;
  return $d * $multiply_table{$s};
}

my @field_list = qw'Date Camera Head Duration Activity';

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { eol => "\n" } );

# print header
$csv->print( \*STDOUT, \@field_list );

# set record separator
local $/ = ('-' x 38) . "\n";

# parse data
while(<>){
  chomp; # remove record separator
  next unless $_; # skip empty section
  my($time,$camdat,@fields) = split m/\n/; # split up the fields

  my %data;


  # split camera and head fields
  @data{qw(Camera Head)} = split /\s+Head\s+/, $camdat;

  # parse lines like:
  #   Duration = 20 s
  #   Activity = 14.9 MBq
  #   Sensitivity = 305 cps/MBq
  for(@fields){
    my($key,$value) = /(\w+) \s* = \s* (.*) /x;
    $data{$key} = $value;
  }

  # at this point we start reducing precision

  $data{Date} = convert_date( $time );

  # remove measurement units
  $data{Duration} = convert_duration($data{Duration}); # safe
  $data{Activity} =~ s/[^\d]*$//; # unsafe

  $csv->print(\*STDOUT, [@data{@field_list}]);
}
```