# Convert specific date in seconds

Tags: datetime, solaris

I need convert the date appears from "ls -la" command from a file, in seconds in **SOLARIS** OS I can't use "date -d" or similar like a Linux SO

4 Dec  9 14:30

Kind Regards,
Arturo

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Which version of Solaris?  What's in `/usr/sfw/bin` or `/usr/gnu/bin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arturo, I second Andrew's comment -- what version of Solaris? -- but I suggest you run `/bin/uname -a` or `cat /etc/release` to report it.

You wrote "convert the date appears from "ls -la" command from a file, in seconds", so I'm assuming you want to print out the time in seconds since the epoch, instead of a more human-readable date.

If you're running a version of Solaris 11, and you have `/usr/gnu/bin`, you can have `/usr/gnu/bin/ls` print out the seconds since the epoch:

```
/usr/gnu/bin/ls -l --time-style="+%s"
```

[See here for details.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54763/ls-1g.html)

I don't have ready access to a Solaris 10 system, but you might be able to use the output of `/bin/ls -le` (giving resolution in seconds) and process it modifying the [awk script in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121896/converting-dates-in-awk):